# Possible to check if a number is IN a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I want to only get those ids where there are 2 rows and one row has the `site_id = 1`, the other `site_id = 2`.

I tried joining the table on twice, but the query took too long.  So what I am now doing is concatenating the site ids, and restricting the rows to only those where 1 is in this concat value, and 28 is in it.  However, I can't get it to work.  It is to do with site_id being a number and my concat values i.e. `sites` being a string?  How can I make sure that both these values are in my concatenated string?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) as num_ids
FROM (
    SELECT id, CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(`site_id`) USING utf8) as `sites`, MAX(`Date_Added`) as `date_added_lb`
    FROM `product_location` pl
    WHERE `site_id` =1 OR `site_id` = 28
    GROUP BY id
) as t
WHERE t.`date_added_lb` >="2013-02-27"
AND 1 IN(`sites`)
AND 28 IN(`sites`)
AND num_ids=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By testing in the `HAVING` clause that the `COUNT(DISTINCT site_id) = 2`  when the `WHERE` clause has already filtered down to `site_id IN (1,28)`, you can validate it without the subquery.

```
SELECT
  id
FROM  production_location
WHERE 
  date_added_lb >= '2013-02-27'
  /* Filters for only site_id 1, 28 */
  AND site_id IN (1, 28)
GROUP BY id
/* And verifies that the group has exactly 2 different results (one of each 1, 28) */
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT site_id) = 2
```

Update:

To verify that only the `site_id = 28` has `date_added_bl >= '2013-02-27'`, you need a slightly smarter subquery:

```
WHERE
  site_id = 1
  OR (site_id = 28 AND date_added_lb >= '2013-02-27')
```

Nothing else needs to change.

If performance doesn't seem to meet your need, verify that there is an index on `site_id`, and one on `id`.  If possible, it may benefit from a composite index on `(id, site_id)`.

Comment: This could work, I was trying to avoid using having though because it can slows down queries apparently.

The other thing is that I need to be able to check that the row for site 28 has the date that is` >= 2013-02-27'`

Comment: That's brilliant.  Thank you.  Very clever with the where clause there.

Comment: Michael Berkowski, that is brilliant. I have been trying different solutions for days now, this one works.

Comment: @KevinDamstra Glad you found it useful.